# Permission denied error while accessing role-id for vault approle

Tags: amazon-web-services, jenkins, terraform, hashicorp-vault

I am trying to create a approle for jenkins using terraform to access the vault. I have added the policy to the role. However, when I am trying to retrieve the role-id and secretid for the role to be passed in jenkins as credentials it gives me error. Below are the codes:

#creating app role

```
 resource "vault_approle_auth_backend_role" "app-proj-jenkins-readonly" {
      backend            = "approle"
      role_name          = "app-proj-jenkins-readonly"
      token_period       = 1800 // 30 Minutes
      secret_id_num_uses = 0
    
      token_policies = [
        vault_policy.app-proj-jenkins-readonly.name,
      ]
      token_bound_cidrs = local.*******_jenkins_bound_cidr_list
    
    }
    
    policy for the role:
    
    # Role needs Read and List so it can get the role-id 
    path "auth/approle/role/app-proj-jenkins-readonly/*" {
      capabilities = ["create", "read", "update", "list", "sudo"]
    
    }
    
    
    When I am trying to access the role-id through vault cli through below cmds:

    vault read auth/approle/role/app-proj-jenkins-readonly/*/role-id

    Error reading from: [object Object].
    URL: /v1/%5Bobject%20Object%5D
    Code: 403
    Errors:
      1 error occurred:
        * permission denied
    
    vault read auth/approle/role/app-proj-jenkins-readonly/role-id

    Error reading from: auth/approle/role/app-proj-jenkins-readonly/role-id.
    URL: /v1/auth/approle/role/app-proj-jenkins-readonly/role-id
    Code: 403
    Errors:
      1 error occurred:
        * permission denied
```

Comment: @gic186  Can you please help??

Comment: did you fix the issue?